# Is the Stuxnet worm a government facade?

Tags: history, politics, technology, war, government

I just read about [Stuxnet](http://www.wired.com/2014/11/countdown-to-zero-day-stuxnet/), which is allegedly a computer worm that silently infected thousands of computers and eventually sabotaged Iran’s nuclear program. I find it difficult to believe that *so many* hoops were jumped through without ever being detected.

Rumors *still* prevail that carrots are good for your vision, but we now know that this was [just a government facade](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/a-wwii-propaganda-campaign-popularized-the-myth-that-carrots-help-you-see-in-the-dark-28812484/?utm_campaign=20130813&utm_medium=socialmedia&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_content=foodandthinkcarrotswwii) to keep the existence of [Airborne interception RADAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airborne_interception_radar) a secret.

Companies (Microsoft and Siemens in this case) could cooperating with governments to permit targeted security "flaws" to prevail. **Did the alleged events surrounding Stuxnet actually happen, or is it a facade to hide manufactured security holes that allow government manipulation of global systems?**

Comment: I feel like there are two questions here: 1) "Is the official report accurate?" and 2) "Was Stuxnet a government hoax to cover other malicious activity?"  IMHO #1 is a more interesting and useful question, #2 is probably unanswerable.

Comment: Second paragraph irrelevant for the question.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) I think there may be a good question in here, but I can't understand it yet. If the common understanding of Stuxnet is correct, it *was* government subterfuge. (Is that what you mean by "facade"?) Your claim (that manufacturers deliberately worked in secret with the Government) is unfalsifiable.

Comment: Stuxnet was uncovered by the Russian firm Kaspersky.